# Multiple Y columns scatter plot color by with IronPython

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

I create scatter plot with  IronPython (2.7.7) (Spotfire 7.11): I have many columns on Y axis. Excerpt from the code below:

```
plot = page.Visuals.AddNew[ScatterPlot]()
plot.Data.DataTableReference = dataTable
plot.XAxis.Expression = "<minSize>"
plotCols = getPlotCols(dataTable)
plot.MarkerSize = 2.0
plot.ShapeAxis.DefaultShape = MarkerShape(MarkerType.Circle)
plot.YAxis.Expression = plotCols
```

The scatter-plot is created, but I get the following error message:

> With multiple columns on y axis, "(Column Names)" has to be selected
>   on X-axis or used to color by ...

[image]

When I click on the side panel 'Color by:' and select (Column Names), I get exactly the desired output.
I want to achieve this output using the IronPython script, without additional clicking.

I have tried the following:

```
plot.ColorAxis.Expression = plotCols #same format as YAxis "[colname1],[colname2], ...etc"
```

I have tried many permutations of how to write (Column Names) to `ColorAxis.Expression` like "(Column Names)", "[(Column Names)]", ... all without the effect.

I have faith that this must be possible. Can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone else is interested in answer, I found the solution:

```
plot.ColorAxis.Expression = "<[Axis.Default.Names]>"
```

This was the line needed. it's strange that, even now when I know solution, I still can't find it anywhere. So let it be documented here.